# Is there a better way to count results from API

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This might be a newbie question.

I am pretty sure I am not doing this the most efficient way.  Bottom line, I have tickets that have severity and status.  I want to calculate how many of each severity and how many of each status.  Is this lengthy way the right way to go about it?

I feel like I should be turning the const into dynamically generated name based on every possible result in half a dozen lines instead of this way.

Thanks in advance

```
    const totalTicketsCount = useMemo(() => {
        if (!tickets?.results) {
            return 0;
        }

        return tickets.results.length;
    }, [tickets]);

    const newTicketsCount = useMemo(() => {
        if (!tickets?.results) {
            return 0;
        }

        return tickets.results.filter(ticket => ticket.status === 'new').length;
    }, [tickets]);

    const inProgressTicketsCount = useMemo(() => {
        if (!tickets?.results) {
            return 0;
        }

        return tickets.results.filter(ticket => ticket.status === 'in_progress').length;
    }, [tickets]);

    const closedTicketsCount = useMemo(() => {
        if (!tickets?.results) {
            return 0;
        }

        return tickets.results.filter(ticket => ticket.status === 'closed').length;
    }, [tickets]);

    // Calculate the ratio
    const ratio = 100 / totalTicketsCount;

    const criticalCount = useMemo(() => {
        if (!tickets?.results) {
            return 0;
        }

        return tickets.results.filter(ticket => ticket.severity === 'critical').length;
    }, [tickets]);

    const highCount = useMemo(() => {
        if (!tickets?.results) {
            return 0;
        }

        return tickets.results.filter(ticket => ticket.severity === 'high').length;
    }, [tickets]);

    const mediumCount = useMemo(() => {
        if (!tickets?.results) {
            return 0;
        }

        return tickets.results.filter(ticket => ticket.severity === 'medium').length;
    }, [tickets]);

    const lowCount = useMemo(() => {
        if (!tickets?.results) {
            return 0;
        }

        return tickets.results.filter(ticket => ticket.severity === 'low').length;
    }, [tickets]);

    const informationalCount = useMemo(() => {
        if (!tickets?.results) {
            return 0;
        }

        return tickets.results.filter(ticket => ticket.severity === 'informational').length;
    }, [tickets]);
```

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but useMemo should never be used until you know you need it (don’t optimize prematurely). If you don’t know you need it, you don’t need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can create new custom hook `useTickets.js` and usually these custom hooks are placed in `hooks` -folder.

Current documentation for custom hooks: https://react.dev/learn/reusing-logic-with-custom-hooks

The `useMemo` hook is not helping here as `tickets.result` is an object reference and will change on every render if not passed from memoed reference. `useMemo` only works with primitives (string, boolean, number etc).

Here is something that you can use to get started:

```
// FILE: useTickets.js
// HERE: ticketsData = tickets.results
export const useTickets = (ticketsData) => {

  const data = Array.isArray(ticketsData) ? ticketsData : [];

  const ticketsCount = data.length;

  // By using reduce, we need to loop the array just once = Complexity O(1) so it's faster than doing multiple filters etc.
  const ticketsDetails = data.reduce((acc, ticket) => {
    const result = acc; // acc = current value of result

    result.countByStatus[ticket.status] += 1;
    result.countBySeverity[ticket.severity] += 1;

    return result;
  }, { // this is the initial state of acc
      countByStatus: {
        new: 0,
        in_progress: 0,
        closed: 0
      },
      countBySeverity: {
        critical: 0,
        high: 0,
        medium: 0,
        low: 0
      }
  });

  return {
    totalCount: ticketsCount,
    ...ticketsDetails
  };
};
```

and to use this hook just import it into your script and call like:

```
const ticketsDetails = useTickets(tickets.results);
```